# python: print max value of a variable for each value of another variable

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given this pandas dataframe, I am trying to print the maximum value of time for each value under categ. For instance, since max time of A=6, max time of B=9 and  max time of C=9, I would like to print something like time=9:2, time=6:1.
How would you do it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

data=[[1, 1,2 ,5,'A'],
        [2, 5,5,6,'A'],
        [3, 4,6,6,'A']
        ,[5, 6,5,6,'A'],
        [7,9,9,7,'B'],
        [8, 7,9,4,'B']
        ,[9, 2,3,8,'B'],
        [2, 5,1,9,'B'],
        [2,2,10,9,'C']
        ,[2, 8,2,8,'C'],
        [9, 5,4,10,'C'],
        [6, 8,5 ,10,'C']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time','x','y','target','categ'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 'categ' and apply `max` to obtain the maximum  per group, then count the values using [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
res = df.groupby('categ')['time'].max().value_counts()
[print(f"time={a}:{b}") for a,b in zip(res.index, res.values)]
```

---

```
time=9:2
time=5:1
```

Comment: I am sorry, when you posted your comment it did not have the `value_counts`. Please post it as an answer and I'll gladly remove mine ;)

Comment: thank you both, but for instance, how would you print that 5 appears once and 9 appears twice ?

Comment: how would you print them in time ascending order ?

Comment: @etckml: Use `ascending = True` in the `sort_values` `value_counts(ascending=True)`

Comment: I mean time-ascending. Your line prints them in 'amount-ascending' order

Comment: then add `.sort_index()` after `value_counts()`

Comment: Now I am getting what I was looking for but in the following format ['time=0:10', 'time=1:20'] etc... How should I extract only number 10 and 20 as integers or floats, without time=0 etc... ?

Comment: @etckml why don't you ask directly and explicitly what you expect in your question? Provide the intended output, it will more efficient than having to go through rounds of comments

Comment: you are right, but as I unfortunately do not have a lot of experience, I did not know what kind of output to expect, :)

Comment: @etckml: `res.values` will give you your values. You can play with the code as you want. I guess you can experiment :)

Comment: @etckml you are probably trying to achieve some goal? what is it? or are you just exploring the language?

Comment: my goals keep evolving according to the produced outcome, so a little bit of both I guess, lol ! Maybe you can help me with my new question which follows from this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504000/determine-values-of-a-pandas-column-located-at-the-same-row-as-specific-values-o

Comment: how do you get the row location of res ?